# Python Altair Radial Plot for Multiple Variables

Tags: python, visualization, streamlit, altair

I'm trying to make a radial plot using altair and streamlit to display two parameters about various car manufacturers.  My data frame looks like this:

| make | count | value | value_int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MERCEDES-BENZ | 8637 | 21.0283 | 21 |
| FORD | 9405 | 22.0488 | 22 |
| SKODA | 10617 | 26.6724 | 26 |
| TOYOTA | 10903 | 24.2498 | 24 |
| VOLKSWAGEN | 11178 | 25.4069 | 25 |
| OPEL | 11672 | 28.5445 | 28 |

and my code looks like this:

```
#d3 is the data frame above
p1 = alt.Chart(d3).encode(
            theta = alt.Theta('value:Q', stack = True),
            radius = alt.Radius('count', scale = alt.Scale(zero = True, rangeMin = 20)),
            color  = alt.Color('make:N', legend = alt.Legend(orient = 'top'))
        ).properties(
            height = 600
        )
        p11 = p1.mark_arc()


        st.altair_chart(p11)
```

and my output looks like this:

[image: My plot looks like this]

I expect to see radial bars, colored by make, that have either the count or the value (I don't really care which way round they are although value would be preferable on the radial) and the theta being the other.  When I set Theta / Radius to be the same then the colour plots as expected but with less information about the data set.  I tried making them integer values and this didn't change anything.  I tried changing the scale from sqrt to linear (linear shown) and again no difference.

Any thoughts?  It seems like it should be relatively simple to make two different columns refer to two different parameters of a graph.  I expect it's something relatively simple that I've missed.

Tried changing graphical parameters, type of values being plotted, different graphical parameters within altair and streamlit. All ended up with not plotting both variables across the whole set.

Comment: Referring to the example in the [reference](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/radial_chart.html), both angle and radius must be the same item. In your example, the graph would be created by specifying a count value for both the angle and the radius. `...theta = alt.Theta('count:Q', stack = True), radius = alt.Radius('count', scale = alt.Scale(zero = True, rangeMin = 20)),...`

Comment: I understand that the reference has both the same parameter, and I've successfully replicated that using my own data.  I want to expand on the example where the radial and angular coordinates are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your script is that the dataframe was not properly sorted in descending order by the "count" column.

That's why when the Opel arc was drawn last, it covered up the other arcs and making it appear as if there was only one color in the chart.

Here is the modified script with the data table sorted properly, I am not sure if it what you wanted:

```
d3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'make': ['MERCEDES-BENZ', 'FORD', 'SKODA', 'TOYOTA', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'OPEL'],
    'count': [8637, 9405, 10617, 10903, 11178, 11672],
    'value': [21.0283, 22.0488, 26.6724, 24.2498, 25.4069, 28.5445],
    'value_int': [21, 22, 26, 24, 25, 28]
})

# Sort the data table by the "count" column in descending order
d3 = d3.sort_values('count', ascending=False)

p1 = alt.Chart(d3).encode(
    theta=alt.Theta('value:Q', stack=True),
    radius=alt.Radius('count', scale=alt.Scale(zero=True, rangeMin=20)),
    color=alt.Color('make:N', legend=alt.Legend(orient='top'))
).properties(
    height=600
)
p11 = p1.mark_arc()

st.altair_chart(p11)
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely progress.  I was hoping that I could get a plot like the example mentioned in one of the earlier answers where the angular component was related to the proportion and the radial value was related to the value.  I think I plotted it the other way round for the example, I've tried a lot of different ways to get this to work.

Comment: Note that for the purpose of solving the problem, I don't really care which goes on the radial and which on the angular component.  If it works for one configuration it will work on the flipped one too.  I've managed to replicate your changes, so thankyou.

Comment: you're welcome, i am not sure, that even if it's possible it will be easy to interpret. What kind of message do you want to deliver with this encoding? Probably you can reach it with a simpler approach, like a scatter diagram

Comment: I'm looking into new and engaging ways to display vehicle pollution data.  I don't want to go into any more depth in case someone tries to spin the data to suit their political aims. There's two ways a manufacturer can be a high contributor: either by having lots of vehicles or having high emissions.  I want to show how these two variables interact with one another.  We've looked at it using cartesian coordinates but the plot looks very clunky.  I was hoping that displaying it in polar coordinates might be better.

Comment: IMHO: If you want to continue this approach, you will need to go deeper into the API and write something bespoke. I tried the Echarts library; they have different types of roseType for nightingale charts (area, radius). See my example here: https://codepen.io/ngolos/pen/zYJvZLo. Although the script allows for two datasets to be inputted, only one is represented on the chart. I also saw the same request posted on the Echarts forum; their answer was that it would be too difficult to interpret. If you believe your audience can do it, you will need to do it yourself.